# Using SendOwl License API To License A Theme

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, shopify

I'm currently working on a Shopify theme that I plan on selling. I am looking into different options I have to properly license the theme.

I have found one solution, SendOwl -
 https://www.sendowl.com/developers/api/licenses

Shopify themes are limited to html/css/js/liquid, no server side code, so I would have to use JS.

**Would this API let me check if the license key entered by the user is valid using only JS?**

**If it is possible, is it safe to include the JS code within the theme, or should I have the license check done away from Shopify (on my own server for example)?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As written in the sendowl API documentation link you posted, you should have own server which requests their API to keep your API key private secret not distribute it in your JS.

In the JS part, you would just need to request your server

Comment: Ok thanks. Could someone just remove the call to the server in the JS file though, thus avoiding purchasing the theme / "nulling it"?

Comment: Yes, actually as soon anyone loads your theme in his browser, he already downloaded `JS/HTML/CSS` files. So he yes could remove the verification, if he has the skill.

Comment: I think i'll just save my time and money and not bother paying for a license system. It's far too easy to remove. Thanks